# Performing calculations using angular forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an Angular form in which all the inputs are numbers, and i want to add and subtract certain fields together and output the value in a separate form field. I managed to get the fields to calculate, however they require that the values have commas separating for every thousand. As well as a currency prefix for the number.

Example: $100,000,000

However this then changes the field to be NaN and thus my calculation functions fail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also there are multiple templates for these calculations, what would be easiest for multiple of them. Would i create a separate component for each calculation template or can i define a class for each template and import it?

Here's some of my current code:

Template

```
<h2>Income Statement</h2>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div fxLayout="row">
  <div class="container col-md-6">
    <div fxLayout="column">
    <h3>New Values</h3>
    <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip>2019/11/14</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
    <form style="padding-right: 10px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">Revenue</label>
        <input [ngModel]="revenue" ui-money-mask (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="revenue" name="revenue" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">- Cost Of Sales</label>
        <input [ngModel]="costOfSales" (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="costOfSales" name="costOfSales" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset"><strong>= Gross Profit</strong></label>
        <input style="border-color:green;" [ngModel]="grossProfits" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="number" class="form-control" id="grossProfit" name="grossProfits" (click)="getGrossProfit()" required placeholder="0" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">- Operating Expense</label>
        <input [ngModel]="operatingExpenses" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="operatingExpense" name="operatingExpenses" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">+ Operating Income</label>
        <input [ngModel]="operatingIncome" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="operatingIcome" name="operatingIncome" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset"><strong>= EBITDA</strong></label>
        <input [ngModel]="ebitda" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="ebitda" name="ebitda" (click)="getEBITDA()" required placeholder="0" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">- Depreciation/Amortisation</label>
        <input [ngModel]="depreciation" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="depreciation" name="depreciation" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset"><strong>= EBIT</strong></label>
        <input [ngModel]="ebit" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="ebit" name="ebit" (click)="getEBIT()" required readonly placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">+ Income Interest</label>
        <input [ngModel]="incomeInterest" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeInterest" name="incomeInterest" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">- Interest Expense</label>
        <input [ngModel]="interestExpense" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="interestExpense" name="interestExpense" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">+ Extraordinary Items</label>
        <input [ngModel]="extraordinaryItems" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="extraordinaryItems" name="extraordinaryItems" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">+ Other Income</label>
        <input [ngModel]="otherIncome" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="otherIncome" name="otherIncome" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset"><strong>= Net Profit before tax</strong></label>
        <input [ngModel]="netProfitBeforeTax" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="netProfitBeforeTax" name="netProfitBeforeTax" (click)="getNetBeforeTax()" required placeholder="0" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset">- Tax</label>
        <input [ngModel]="tax" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="tax" name="tax" required placeholder="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fundGrossAsset"><strong>= Net Profit After Tax</strong></label>
        <input [ngModel]="netProfitAfterTax" covenantsCurrencyFormatter (ngModelChange)="testPrice=$event" type="text" class="form-control" id="netProfitAfterTax" name="netProfitAfterTax" (click)="getNetAfterTax()" required placeholder="0" readonly>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Component

```
    templateForm: FormGroup;
      templateFormSub: Subscription;
      calculations: FormArray;

      totalDebt = 0.00;
      fundGrossAsset = 0.00;
      submitted = false;

      result: number;
      resultheading: any;

      revenue: number;
      costOfSales: number;
      grossProfits: number;
      operatingExpenses: number;
      operatingIncome: number;
      ebitda: number;
      depreciation: number;
      ebit: number;
      incomeInterest: number;
      interestExpense: number;
      extraordinaryItems: number;
      otherIncome: number;
      netProfitBeforeTax: number;
      tax: number;
      netProfitAfterTax: number;
       constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {}

    onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }

      getGrossProfit(revenue, costOfSales, grossProfits) {

        grossProfits = +this.revenue - +this.costOfSales;
      }

      getEBITDA(grossProfits, operatingExpenses, operatingIncome) {
        this.ebitda = this.grossProfits - this.operatingExpenses + this.operatingIncome;
      }

      getEBIT(ebitda, depreciation, ebit) {
        this.ebit = this.ebitda - this.depreciation;
      }

      getNetBeforeTax(ebit, incomeInterest, interestExpense, extraordinaryItems, otherIncome) {
        this.netProfitBeforeTax = this.ebit + this.incomeInterest - this.interestExpense + this.extraordinaryItems + this.otherIncome;
      }

      getNetAfterTax(netProfitBeforeTax, tax) {
        this.netProfitAfterTax = this.netProfitBeforeTax - this.tax;
      }

      getResult() {
        this.result = this.netProfitAfterTax;
      }
```

Comment: You could replace all the commas and currencies with empty spaces and then perform the calculation. Would that help?

Comment: You have to convert the inputs to comma-separated values on every keypress and whenever you have to do any calculations, first convert them again to integer and then use the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A converter method? Use text based inputs, but when you calculate these values convert the values back to number, an when the calculation finished convert back to string. See in my example: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dguxh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

```js
  convertToNumber(value: string): number {
    return parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  }

  convertToString(value: number): string {
    if (value.toString().indexOf(".") > -1) {
      const decimal = value.toString().split(".")[1];
      return (
        this.convertToStringUtil(value.toString().split(".")[0]) + "." + decimal
      );
    } else {
      return this.convertToStringUtil(value.toString());
    }
  }

  convertToStringUtil(value: string): string {
    return value
      .split("")
      .reverse()
      .reduce((accum, value, index, { length }) => {
        return (
          accum +
          value +
          ((index + 1) % 3 === 0 && index !== length - 1 ? "," : "")
        );
      }, "")
      .split("")
      .reverse()
      .join("");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the best way to go, however I am still confused as to how I will use it with my front end html. Do I use this method on my calculations function to convert the user input first then after the calculation, convert back to string?

Comment: Yes. Holds all value in string format in the variables, and just convert the values in the calculation functions. First converts to number, makes calculations and then converts back to string and saves the results.

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert your all variables and use them on your functions.
For example:

```
getEBITDA(grossProfits, operatingExpenses, operatingIncome) {

    grossProfits = Number(grossProfits.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    operatingExpenses = Number(operatingExpenses.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    operatingIncome = Number(operatingIncome.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

    this.ebitda = grossProfits - operatingExpenses + operatingIncome;
}
```

do this for all other functions.